# Updating previous variable with the current one within a loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have "price offer" items under certain processes;

```
PROCESS 1
index no 0      price offer a   count=1 ($selected_price_offers_cnt)

PROCESS 2
index no 1      price offer b   count=3     (3+1=4)
index no 2      price offer c   count=3     (3+1=4)
index no 3      price offer d   count=3     (3+1=4) 3=selected_price_offers_cnt, 1=$previous, 4=$next 


PROCESS 3
index no 4      price offer e   count=2     (2+4=6)
index no 5      price offer f   count=2     (2+4=6) 2=selected_price_offers_cnt, 4=$previous, 6=$next
```

What I need to do is to print "scale sub total" only below the LAST price offer item of EACH PROCESSES. In other words, below **a**, **d** and **f**.

In order to do that I try to compare the latest count of the price offers from the beginning (1, 4 and 6) with the current row index no + 1. 
If we arrive at the last price offer of a PROCESS X, its count will be == index no + 1 (like at process offer d count 4 = index no 3 + 1). 
So I need to keep $previous variable updated with $next for the following PROCESS Y.

My code takes unnaturally long time to finish execution and at last it prints only one sale sub total line.
(As this code is used inside Drupal views global php field, SQL queries are arranged to work there and they return correct values, no problem there.)
Any approaches other than while...loop is also welcomed.

```
<?php 
$process_nid = $row->nid_3;
$current_index_no = $view->row_index; //the number of the row that is being processed

$selected_price_offers = db_query("SELECT entity_id FROM drupal_field_data_field_process WHERE bundle = 'price_offer' AND deleted = '0' AND field_process_nid = {$process_nid} AND entity_id IN (SELECT content_id FROM drupal_flag_counts WHERE fid='18' AND content_type='node' AND COUNT = '1')");
$selected_price_offers_cnt = db_query("SELECT COUNT(entity_id) FROM drupal_field_data_field_process WHERE bundle = 'price_offer' AND deleted = '0' AND field_process_nid = {$process_nid} AND entity_id IN (SELECT content_id FROM drupal_flag_counts WHERE fid='18' AND content_type='node' AND COUNT = '1')")->fetchField();

$previous = 0;
while($current_index_no) { 

$next = $selected_price_offers_cnt + $previous; // add the previous to the current amount

if ($next == ($current_index_no+1)) {

$previous = $next; // save the new price offer count to the $previous in order to use it at the next row

// this part below works as expected
$sum1 = 0;
foreach($selected_price_offers as $item) {
$po_item= $item->entity_id;
$scale1 = db_query("SELECT field_sub_total_scale_1_value FROM drupal_field_data_field_sub_total_scale_1 WHERE bundle = 'price_offer' AND deleted = '0' AND entity_id = {$po_item}")->fetchField();
  $sum1+= $scale1;
}
  print "scale sub total:&nbsp;".number_format($sum1,2,",","."). " TL";
}
else {
echo "";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Please use code box for your codes otherwise we dont understand what is going on with this messy alphabetic characters.

Comment: Sorry, I edited all. Thanks.

Comment: Türkçe konuşayım, ne yapmaya çalıştığını anlamadım. Biraz daha detay verir misin?

Comment: Selam, "while" infinite loopa sebep oluyor... if kullanırsam da if dışarısındaki $previous değişkenini if içerisinden $next ile güncelleyemiyorum, $previous = 0 ile başlıyor her zaman. Yapmaya çalıştığım şey, her bir Process için o processe ilişkin son price offer'a ulaşıldığını anlayıp sub total print etmek...